# Algoritmo para buscar la mayor de la sumas en una lista

Tags: c#

Necesito alguna manera de encontrar la mejor manera de buscar una suma que se aproxime lo máximo a un parámetro de entrada en un método

```
      public int MejorSuma(int numero, int suma, List<int> lista) {
            ....
      }
```

Quiero crear una función con tres parametros;

El parametro **"numero"** determina el numero de variables a sumar de la lista.

El parámetro **"suma"** es el valor máximo que se debería alcanzar, de no existir una combinación exacta debería quedarme con la mejor de las combinaciones, pero nunca pasarme.

El parámetro **"lista"** es una lista de int.

Ejemplo;

```
    lista = new List<int> {91, 74, 73, 85, 73, 81, 87};
    n = this.MejorSuma(230, 3, lista);
```

En lo que **"n"** debería darme un valor de **228**, que es la mejor de las combinaciones... Llevo varios días intentando buscarme una buena solución sin "enmarranar" el programa demasiado.

La lista tendrá siempre un numero de variables mayor que el valor del parámetro "suma" es ahí donde me atasco, no se que algoritmo crear para buscar todas las combinaciones posibles...

Comment: lo que estas buscando (el algoritmo) se parece mucho al del problema del viajero https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_del_viajante, solo que en tu caso los valores son las distancias entre ciudades, y que quieres buscar una distancia en concreto, no todo el recorrido. Quizas pueda ayudarte, echale un vistazo.

Comment: Tendrías que tener tantos bucles como indica el valor n (3 en tu ejemplo) y al ir recorriendo el listado, tienes que guardar el resultado de la suma, para ir comprobando si alguna combinación se acerca más al resultado que quieres obtener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En principio no es muy complicado lo que buscas. Quizá lo mas complejo sea encontrar todas las combinaciones de elementos de la lista tomados de n en n. Para conseguir eso, usamos el siguiente método de extensión que hace uso de LINQ y recursividad:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Combinaciones<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elementos, int n)
{
    return n == 0 ? new[] { new T[0] } :
        elementos.SelectMany((e, i) =>
        elementos.Skip(i + 1).Combinaciones(n - 1).Select(c => (new[] { e }).Concat(c)));
}
```

Una vez tenémos este método, es trivial codificar el método `MejorSuma`:

```
public int MejorSuma(int suma, int numero, List<int> lista)
{
    var combinaciones = lista.Combinaciones(numero);

    int maxsuma = 0;
    foreach (var c in combinaciones)
    {
        int sumaParcial = c.Sum();
        if (sumaParcial>maxsuma && sumaParcial<=suma)
        {
            maxsuma = sumaParcial;
        }
    }
    return maxsuma;
}
```

Usando tu ejemplo de datos:

```
var lista1 = new List<int> { 91, 74, 73, 85, 73, 81, 87 };
int n = this.MejorSuma(230, 3, lista1);
//n=228
```

*El código del método de extensión está tomado de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33336576/579895)*